# Mouse hover not working in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to do a mouse hover function on the menu in Cricinfo website.

It's not throwing any error and also the intended operation is not done.

Can anyone suggest me where the problem is or a possible way to find a way to debug it.

```
File file = new File(".\\Config\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/series/index.html?view=current");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Thread.sleep(7000);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement eleFirstLevel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a  [@href='/ci/engine/match/index.html?view=live']"));
action.moveToElement(eleFirstLevel).perform();
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[3]"))).click().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.quit();
```

Comment: What is the error? What is the the operation that you expect vs what it is actually doing? Include screenshots, please. [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Xpath:-

```
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[3]"))).click().build().perform();
```

Check this code:

```
driver.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/series/index.html?view=current");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Thread.sleep(7000);
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
WebElement eleFirstLevel=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a  [@href='/ci/engine/match/index.html?view=live']")); 
action.moveToElement(eleFirstLevel).perform();
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav_grp']/li[2]/div[2]/ul/li[3]"))).click().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.close();
```

Comment: Even if this xpath is wrong, it should show extended menu for following piece of code-         WebElement eleFirstLevel=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a  [@href='/ci/engine/match/index.html?view=live']")); 
    action.moveToElement(eleFirstLevel).perform();
This is also not working..